# Selecting from database WHERE somefield contains one of the value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have one straight forward script that returns user data if access code is correct.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE access_codes = '$CODE' ";
$rs = $mysqli->query($sql);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
if ($rows == 1) {
    //CODE IS FOUND, RETURN USERNAME AND PASSWORD
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
    $username = $row['username'];
    $password = $row['password'];
    mysqli_close($mysqli); // Closing Connection
    header("Location: http://GOTONEXTPAGE.COM");
    die();

} else {
    //CODE IS NOT FOUND
    mysqli_close($mysqli); // Closing Connection
    exit;
}
```

It works fine, if access_codes contains only 1 value.

But what i want to achive is that access_codes can contain several codes, separated with space ex: 123456 654321 0101020304.

And i could still retrive userdata if **ANY** of these codes is found.

Can i do this with query, or i need to work around with php?

Regards
M

Comment: You use IN insted of= and replace empty spaces with commas

Comment: @Mihai I think you have it backwards. The database contains space-separated numbers, `$CODE` just contains one of them.

Comment: e.g select * From Table Where somecolumn in(1,2,3)

Comment: @Barmar Right you are,my parsing has bugs.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Is the list of codes in `$CODE` or is it in the database column? If it's in the database, it would be better if you normalized the schema.

Comment: @Barmar, oh I do hope not, I'm getting tired of that particular design error

Comment: use IN clause . visit below link.you can understand how it works. 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Comment: @jQuery Read my above comments -- IN is not what he needs.

Comment: @Barmar `access_codes can contain several codes` it seems is in the database.

Comment: Look here http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php

Comment: $code contains 1 of the codes, database field contains several.

Comment: @user2033139 you may use `LIKE '%$CODE%'` but is not an option.

Comment: Before I answer: Is it possible for two users to have the same access code, or is an access code unique to one user?

Comment: Every user has theyr own unique codeS.

Answer (score 2):

It would be best if you normalized the schema. Make a table of access codes where there's one row for each combination of `userID` and `access_code`. Then you can use a `JOIN` between this table and the `users` table to get the users with a particular access code.

If you can't redesign, you can use a regular expression:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE access_code RLIKE CONCAT('[[:<:]]', ?, '[[:>:]]')";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $CODE);
$stmt->execute();
```

`[[:<:]]` and  `[[:>:]]` match word boundaries, so this will only match when the code is a whole word in the column.

Answer (score 0):

```
$codes = "123456 654321 0101020304";
$expCodes = explode(" ", $codes);

$code = implode("', '", $expCodes);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE access_codes IN ('{$code}') ";
// do your query
```